# Wishing Chayim Aruchim to Non-Mourners

Tags: blessing, family-members, sitting-shiva

Among not yet frum people the traiditional blessing of haMakom is not used but rather people wish each other ' a long life or chayim aruchim' whilst this term is reserved for avelimg. Is there any issur in wishing 'long life' to other family members of the deceased but not the close members sitting shiva? Does one have to distinguish between what he wishes an avel and someone just close

Comment: Is your question assuming one *does* wish long life to the ones sitting _shiv'a_? (If so, you may wish to edit that into your question, and the basis for that assumption.)

Comment: Is this in the Bais HaAveil? Is this a greeting normally reserved for who? Question needs some polishing, I am not sure what you are asking?

Comment: possibly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12690/759

Comment: This question still requires a great deal of cleanup to be sufficiently comprehensible. Does "whilst this term is reserved for avelim" refer to "not yet frum" practice" or normative practice"? Either way, do you have a source? Please specify clearly what exactly you suspect might be forbidden and why.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22460&pgnum=279

HaRav Tzvi Pesach Frank Zatzal says that you may say Chaim Aruchim to the mourners and it is not considered like a greeting.

Comment: I'm not sure this entirely answers the question.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is as you can see in my comments to the question. If Moshe Yitzhak elaborates and explains what he is looking for then I may edit my answer.

Comment: Gershon, if a question is not clear, I recommend commenting, downvoting, and/or voting to close rather than filling in your own assumptions and answering the question as-is.