# Saying goodbye on Tisha B'Av

Tags: halacha, mourning-aveilus, speech-talking, tisha-bav

On Tisha B'Av, the custom is to refrain from greeting people. Even a brief "hello" is to be avoided if possible. Does the same restriction apply to saying "good-bye"? Or is that not considered a greeting for this purpose?

Comment: Very similar http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12690/mourning-greetings

Answer (score 6):

No, Rav Shmuel Kamenetsky in sefer Kovetz Halchos 232:13 that saying "shalom" is forbidden but to say "see you later" or "good night" before one goes to sleep is not a problem, but "good morning" is. See footnotes in the book if you have access to it.

Comment: IIRC Harav Yishak writes specifically that good morning should be permissible.

Comment: Could be ,just quoting from Rav Shmuel ,will check footnote when I get a chance where it says who says good morning is assur.

Comment: What's the difference between Good Night and Good Morning?

Comment: @doubleAA , Rav Shmuel says that the diffrence between good morning is because one is greeting another which is assur , but good night is like saying see you later it is not a greeting.

Answer (score 1):

I heard from my Rav that even "see you later" or "good-bye" is forbidden for a mourner and on Tisha BAv.