# Are you allowed to wish someone "Gut Mo'ed" on Tish'a B'Av

Tags: halacha, tisha-bav

[MB Orach Chayim 454:20](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14166&st=&pgnum=66) says that you are not allowed to say "She'elat Shalom" Mishnah Brurah commentary (41) says that even "Good morning" is prohibited.

Tish'a B'av is called a "mo'ed" in Eicha. Therefore, can I wish someone "Gut Mo'ed" on Tish'a B'av, or would this be considered in the category of "Sh'elat Shalom"?

Comment: It will eventually be a Moed,no? Even though we don't say tachnun

Comment: @sam - It IS one, now!

Comment: I REM learning that medrash ,was it that pashut?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12690/759

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ohr Someach](http://ohr.edu/1098) gives the halocho as:

> Greeting someone with "good morning" and the like is prohibited. One
>   who is greeted should answer softly and, if possible, inform the
>   person of the prohibition.

"Gut Mo'ed" seems as much a greeting as "Good morning and the like" which are prohibited and may undesirably elicit a more light-hearted response since it is unusual which would be another reason not to allow it.